# how to organize the layout to make it responsive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

this is my code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="page-header"> Utenti online </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- fine row1 -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="margin:10px">
                <div class="useronline">
                    <img src="images/no-photo.png" class="img-responsive" width="150" style="border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; margin-bottom:10px">
                    <b style="margin:10px;"> Marco </b>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="margin:10px">
                <div class="useronline">
                    <img src="images/no-photo.png" class="img-responsive" width="150" style="border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; margin-bottom:10px">
                    <b style="margin:10px;"> Marco </b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="margin:10px">
                <div class="useronline">
                    <img src="images/no-photo.png" class="img-responsive" width="150" style="border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; margin-bottom:10px">
                    <b style="margin:10px;"> Marco </b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="margin:10px">
                <div class="useronline">
                    <img src="images/no-photo.png" class="img-responsive" width="150" style="border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; margin-bottom:10px"/>
                    <b style="margin:10px;"> Marco </b>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="margin:10px">
                <div class="useronline">
                    <img src="images/no-photo.png" class="img-responsive" width="150" style="border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; margin-bottom:10px">
                    <b style="margin:10px;"> Marco </b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the image of the window browser (large screen)
[image]

Now, col-lg is 10 but sm is 25.
My question is: how to organize the layout to make it responsive for all screen?

Comment: It depends on how many images do you want to show on certain breakpoints.

Comment: lg: 5 image, md: 4 images, sm: 3, xs: 2 images

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is responsive on all screens, if you are looking for a consistent behavior across all screen sizes , you can change these lines in code as below:

Change this:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="margin:10px">
```

to this

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2" style="margin:10px">
```

will make all the divs spreading into two columns for all devices.

Sorry i don't have enough points to add as comment, hence adding as an answer.

Comment: i changed my code, but not work because on a tablet 10'' in portait mode the result is this: http://imgur.com/GCdcqpg